# How to access an item in a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I defined a ListView like this:

```
            <ListView     x:Name="libraryBooksListView"
                      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VideoListView"
                      AutomationProperties.Name="Videos"
                      TabIndex="1"
                      Padding="0,0,4,0"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LibraryBooksItemTemplate}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LibraryListViewItemStyle}"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      SelectionMode="None">
        </ListView>
```

and I defined the LibraryBooksItemTemplate like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LibraryBooksItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0">

            <GridView x:Name="booksGridView"
                      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                      AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource textbookTemplateSelector}"
                      SelectionMode="Multiple"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                      ItemClick="booksGridView_ItemClick"
                      SelectionChanged="booksGridView_SelectionChanged"
                      IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            </GridView>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The GridView, booksGridView, has multiple items (books).

1. How to modify/access the "ItemTemplateSelector" and SelectionMode etc. of the GridView?
2. Is there a way to access each of the items in the booksGridView?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

- The easiest one is to wrap your `DataTemplate` contents into a `UserControl`.
- Another one is to use something like [`ContainerFromIndex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromindex.aspx).
- Then you can also use `VisualTreeHelper` class to walk the visual tree.
- Then again you can subclass your `ItemsControl` and override `GetContainerForItemOverride()` or 
  `PrepareContainerForItemOverride()` or
- use the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) property

The imporant thing to note is that your `ItemsSource` provides items to the control while the overrides or the generator provide containers to display the items using the `ItemTemplates`.

*Edit As for your additional questions:

- *How to modify/access the "ItemTemplateSelector" and SelectionMode etc. of the GridView?*
  You have defined your selector resource and gave it a key of "textbookTemplateSelector", so you can just get it with this.Resources["textbookTemplateSelector"]. `SelectionMode` you can bind to the same source `DataContext` you bound your `ItemsSource` to and change or read it through a binding.
- Is there a way to access each of the items in the booksGridView?
  Yes. Since your `DataContext` is set as the `ItemsSource` of your `ListView` - you can access all the items through that `DataContext`. Each of these items seems to have an `Items` property that is bound to your `GridView`, so you can access each of these through the `Items` property you have defined yourself.

Comment: I don't want to wrap the DataTemplate into UserControl because of the ItemClick and SelectionChanged events (they have to act on the libraryBooksListView level)
 
As to your other suggestions can you please elaborate more?
Thx.

Comment: I think the problem is that your question still isn't precise enough. My answer should give you enough clues on how to access specific elements in the UI, but I suspect you really want to get access to the items bound to your UI, but here the solution will really depend on what you want to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by using ItemsSource:

```
foreach(var book in this.booksGridView.ItemsSource)
{
}
```

Comment: booksGridView is a DataTemplate. I would like to be able to "talk" to the GridView in this DataTemplate.
Thx.